# Bing Maps Entity Collection DOM Property

Tags: javascript, bing-maps

Is there any other way to access the 'dom' property of an entity in an EntityCollection?

The reason I ask is that when a user pans/zooms the map far enough, pins are removed from DOM but I have functions that manipulate the pins by adding/removing classes to them. When the pins are not in the DOM, they don't manipulated.

I was drilling in to the somewhat obscure/private property pin.cm1002_er_etr which provided access to the nested 'dom' property, but it seems that depending on the order of initialization of the Entities, the numeric value can change. Now I have to access it with pin.cm1007_er_etr.

It sounds petty, but maintenance wise this could be a nightmare is someone were to add/remove/reorder entities for the application (if that's what is causing the change).

```
function filterRows(){
    var visibleRows = $("#table").DataTable().rows({"search" : "applied"});
    var hiddenRows = $("#table").DataTable().rows({"search" : "removed"});
    var targetGroup = ($("a.MapPushpinBase").length == _entities.PushPinsEntity.getLength()) ? "screen" : "memory";
    for(var i = 0, l1 = visibleRows[0].length; i < l1; i++){
        var row = $("#table").DataTable().row(i);
        var id = row.data().ID;
        if(!$("#"+id).hasClass("radiusPin")){
            toggleIcon(id, "show", targetGroup);
            var index = IDs.indexOf(id);
            if(index == -1 && $(row.node()).hasClass("selected")) IDs.push(id);
        }
    }
    for(var i = 0, l1 = hiddenRows[0].length; i < l1; i++){
        var row = $("#table").DataTable().row(i);
        var id = row.data().ID;
        if(!$("#"+id).hasClass("radiusPin")){
            toggleIcon(uwi, "hide", targetGroup);
            var index = IDs.indexOf(id);
            if(index > -1 && $(row.node()).hasClass("selected")) IDs.splice(index, 1);
        }
    }
    delete visibleRows, hiddenRows;
};
function toggleIcon(id, action, targetGroup){
    var dom = null;
    if(targetGroup == "screen"){
        dom = (id.split("#").length > 1) ? id : "#" + id;
    }
    else if(targetGroup == "memory"){
        for(var i = 0, l = _entities.PushPinsEntity.getLength(); i < l; i++){
            var p = _entities.PushPinsEntity.get(i);
            if(p._id == id){
                dom = p.cm1007_er_etr.dom;
            }
        }
    }
    if(action == "select"){
        $(dom).addClass("selected");
    }
    else if(action == "deselect"){
        $(dom).removeClass("selected");
    }
    else if(action == "hide"){
        $(dom).addClass("hiddenpin");
    }
    else if(action == "show"){
        $(dom).removeClass("hiddenpin");
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think having that kind of access to DOM is possible and also if it's the good approach as the rendering engine might be updated and your code might not be working anymore. So technicaly, you can work on a way to do this but I don't recommend to use the underneath elements.

If you want to add you own class on the DOM element, you can use the `typeName` property on the `PushpinOption` while creating the pushpin.

See the MSDN : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg427629.aspx

So here is a supported way to add behaviors (events, decoration...) based on a custom class name added to the pushpin:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="http://ecn.dev.virtualearth.net/mapcontrol/mapcontrol.ashx?v=7.0">
    </script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var map = null;

        $(function() {

            $('#map').on('click', '.custom-pushpin', function() { console.log('click on custom pin') });

            // Initialize the map
            map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map($('#map').get(0), {
                credentials: "YOURKEY",
                mapTypeId: 'r',
                center: new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.5, 2.75),
                zoom: 4
            });

            // Retrieve the location of the map center 
            var center = map.getCenter();

            // Add a pin to the center of the map
            var pin = new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(center, {text: '1', typeName: 'custom-pushpin'}); 
            map.entities.push(pin);

            // Add a second pin to the center of the map
            var pin = new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(new Microsoft.Maps.Location(48.5, 4.75), {text: '2', typeName: 'custom-pushpin'}); 
            map.entities.push(pin);
        });

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map" style="position: relative; width: 800px; height: 600px;">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, but my problem isn't with adding properties or values on initialization. My problem is once pins are on the map and user pans/zooms, Bing removes the pin elements from the DOM itself to save on memory when rendering when pins get too far away from the viewable area.  
  
It's at that point where I'm manipulating the "state" of the pin to reflect 4 different colors. When the pins aren't in the DOM, I need to manipulate all the pins so that if the user zooms out or pans enough to pull pins back in the DOM, that those pins will reflect the state change performed.

Comment: Then, I think, that you need to update them using the native methods rather than trying to use the DOM element. What are you doing that cannot be done natively? Share your code if it helps, I'll be glad to try to help you.

Comment: How many pushpins do you have added on the map control (I mean in total)?

Comment: This application is designed for a user to execute a search and return a result set that will display any number of pins anywhere from 1 to 3,000 at a time.

Comment: Somewhat related, I'm also discovering memory issues with these pins because the Map module is loading into the global namespace and because I'm creating events against these pins, although I'm removing the events before the pins are being replaced, the pins are left stuck in the detached dom tree.

Comment: My question regarding the number of pushpins was to know why you don't manipulate them by removing and adding back the elements (with the appropriate styling and events) on the map rather than changing its dynamically generated DOM representation. With 3000 pushpins, it should be performant enough I think.

Comment: Because adding/removing CSS classes is way more efficient than dropping and creating pins just to switch an image.

Comment: Also I'm not doing wholesale changes, some will persist in their original state while others will need to be modified. I'd rather not have to temporarily duplicate the pins in memory as you're suggesting.